# Given a convergence series $\sum 3^na_n$. Prove/disprove: The series $\sum (-2)^na_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given a convergence series $\sum 3^na_n$.

Prove/disprove: The series $\sum (-2)^na_n$ converges.

I guess the arguement is true as this is a power series, but can it be proven formally>

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: The statements concerning the radius of convergence of power series *are* proven formally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power series-less proof:

$\sum 3^na_n$ convergent $\implies$ $(3^na_n)_n\to 0$ $\implies$ $(3^na_n)_n$ bounded. Say $|3^na_n|\le K$. Then,
$$|(-2)^na_n|\le(2/3)^nK$$
and as $\sum(2/3)^nK$ is convergent, $\sum(-2)^na_n$ is absolutely convergent by [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Comment: Why $\sum(2/3)^nK$ is convergent?

Comment: Because it's geometric. Disregard that comment please.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the power series $\sum a_n x^n$. Since $\sum 3^na_n$ converges, the radius of convergence of the power series is $ \ge 3$. Hence, since $|-2| <3$, the series $\sum (-2)^na_n$ converges absolutely.

Comment: Thank you Fred. How can I show it's true or find a proof for this arguement?

Comment: By the root test: $ \lim \sup 3 |a_n|^{1/n} \le 1$. Then $ \lim \sup |-2| |a_n|^{1/n} <1$. Again by the root test, the result follws.

Comment: How do you know this is true - $\lim \sup 3 |a_n|^{1/n} \le 1$? The root test is not iff

Comment: The series $\sum 3^na_n$ is convergent. Suppose that $\lim \sup 3 |a_n|^{1/n} >1$ , then the root test says: $\sum 3^na_n$ is divergent, contradiction.